# proof by cases, redundancy and different outcomes with different cases.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, proof-writing, computer-science

Question is:
If x and y are positive numbers with x >y+1 then x^2 -y^2 is not prime.

I attempted a proof by cases for this problem.
using 4 cases:
x=odd, y = odd
x=odd, y = even
x=even, y = even
x=even, y= odd

for the first case (x=odd, y =odd)
I said:
let x = (2a+1) + 2 I added the 2 because at every instance x must greater than y by at least 2  (x>y+1). 
let y = 2b+1

x^2-y^2 = (2a+3)^2 - (2b+1)^2 
After simplifying my final answer was 4(a^2-b^2+3a-b+2).

So in my proof I said(this isnt my whole proof just a summary) since no matter what ever a or b is the answer will always be even and greater than 2. Therefore making it not a prime number and proving the proposition.

Would this be right? Would I have to continue onto the other cases or would that be redundant? What if another case proves that it can be a prime number?

Case 2 proved that it can be a prime number
x=odd, y= even
let x= (2a+1)+2
let y = 2b

(2+3)^2-(2b)^2 = 4(a^2-b+3a) + 9

Since an even number + an odd number is always an odd number that makes the possibility of the result being prime which contradicts the first case. Does this mean I have to use another method to prove this?

Answer (score 1):

If both $x$ and $y$ are odd numbers with $x>y+1$, then the form of $x$ and $y$ should be $x=2a+1$ and $y=2b+1$ where $a>b$. Just adding $2$ to $x$ without specifying the order of $a$ and $b$ would not be correct.

Proof by cases may not be the easiest approach for solving this problem unless you are told to do so. A direct method might be more fruitful. Just use the facts that both $x-y$ and $x+y$ are positive integers $>1$ and $x^2-y^2=(x-y)(x+y)$.

Comment: How would I incorporate that x > y +1 by just setting x to an odd value? Im confused on how you got integers > 1 and (x-y)(x+y) are you getting that from the fact that x and y are both squared?

Comment: Thanks for the input on me using proof by cases, for future use is it redundant to prove multiple cases if one proof proves/disproves the proposition? Or is that the purpose of using proof by cases to solve multiple cases?

Comment: When $x$ and $y$ are positive integers with $x>y+1$, then $x-y>1$  and also $x+y>2y+1>1$. The fact that $x^2-y^2=(x-y)(x+y)$ is just multiplication and cancellation. Proof by cases is normally used in situations where the hypothesis can be naturally broken down into finite number distinct cases. If other proof methods can prove the proposition more naturally, it is certainly not necessary to use the proof by cases.